# Fastest way to move last N bytes to start of an array?

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, x86

Given an 8-byte array(it is always 8 bytes) of

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

and a `pos` argument between 0 a 7

mutating the array can result in:

```
[pos 0] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
[pos 1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1
[pos 2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2
```

because we start at the element at `pos` and if we are out of elements, we loop back to start of the array for next ones

What's the fastest way on X86 to create the resulting array?

Background:

It's a rolling key that's *part* of an obfuscation algorithm for a network protocol (later on it's part of some XOR operations on data etc.)
I have to implement the protocol as a client, but I can't change the original algorithm.
There is a lot of network traffic being processed, and the algorithm is processing them on byte-after-byte basis in a loop, while also modifying the key, which is slow.
The goal is to process 8 bytes at a time, reducing the overhead.
Having the correct 8 bytes of key I can later "XOR it" with 8 bytes of network data using only one instruction.

Comment: which language? `std::rotate` in C++

Comment: C++ but looking for some low-level solution, preferably one that treats the array as a 64-bit number

Comment: "the fastest" is usually the one that is not too slow, or not slower than an alternative. Did you try `std::rotate` and it did turn out to be not fast enough?

Comment: std::rotate is definitely not what I am looking for as I want something language-agnostic, however the term "rotate left" looks like a good hint and got me to `rol` x86 instruction which I will give a try

Comment: For me some important details has been scrap of. Why do you need this? Do you solve some online problem and you think this is a reason why your solution exceeds time limit? If yes then please provide information about this problem (link is best).

Comment: I added more background to description

Comment: The correct "bitwise" answer is (assuming r as number if bits instead of bytes)
 (x << r) | (x >> (64 - r))

Comment: Not sure yet how to make GCC see the pattern and replace it with "rol" instruction, that's something I will keep researching while I play with [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org)

Comment: If you need to do this repeatedly on the same source array (the key), then a potentially fastest way is to not modify the array at all. Instead, use an array that contains the key twice (last char doesn't need duplication). That way you can can "rotate" simply by modifying an offset pointer.

Comment: Excellent idea, thank you! The only problem left is that the key is modified after each iteration, a constant is added to each byte of the key. That's something I hope to implement with vector instruction hopefully.

Comment: You can add a constant to each byte of the duplicated array almost as easily - as long as you have 128 bit SIMD instructions. If not, you'll need twice as many instructions as with non-duplicated key.

Comment: @underflow: If it's really just adding a constant to create an XOR key, add the constant on the fly.  `paddd` / `pxor` is still very cheap for doing 16 bytes at a time.  If you're copying some network packet and loading key data, the extra ALU uop in that loop may barely affect throughput of that loop.  (And save a whole other loop to modify the key data.)

Comment: I successfully used the "rol" ASM and later vectorized the whole algorithm by pre-computing key rotations ahead. it was hell of a ride with a ton of edge cases!

Comment: Vectorized version is about 20x faster than the standard for-loop version in a quick test :)